# Непонятна структура CSI кодов

Tags: linux, консоль, ascii

В [Википедии](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A3%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8_ANSI) показан вот такой шаблон csi кодов:

> CSI [символ(-ы) режима] n1 ; n2... [замыкающий(-ие) символ(-ы)] буква

Допустим, я хочу установить курсор слева сверху в терминале, тогда я напишу: `printf("\x1b[H");` но если я хочу куда-нибудь в центр поместить этот курсор, как мне указать, куда я хочу поместить его?

Как я понял, нужно написать вот так: `printf("\x1b22;22[H]");`, но это не работает. Напишите, пожалуйста, нормальный шаблон этих csi кодов, и объясните, что такое символы режима. Буду очень благодарен.

Comment: `printf("\x1b[22;22H");`

Comment: @extrn, спасибо. Может напишите это в ответе?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В данном случае квадратные скобки в шаблоне означают, что эта часть выражения не обязательна.

```c
"\x1b[22;22H"
```

Если следовать описанию шаблона из статьи, в данной строке содержатся следующие поля:

```
CSI    n1 ";" n2  буква
\x1b[  22  ;  22  H
```

Символы режима и замыкающие символы в ней (как и в большинстве других повсеместно используемых последовательностях) отсутствуют.